# What is a capture conversion in Java and can anyone give me examples?

Tags: java, capture, jls

I've noticed JLS talks of [5.1.10 Capture Conversion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.10), but I fail to understand what they are.

Can anyone explain them to me/give examples?

Comment: No examples other than in the discussion immediately below?

Comment: That's true, they provide an example, but from it, I couldn't understand what capture conversions are. Did you understand the example? If so, could you kindly explain to me what they are. Thanks.

Comment: Wildcard Capture and Helper Methods 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html
Basically: given a `List<?> i`, the helper method converts the captured wildcard into a known type `<T>` in the helper method, so that now you can invoke a method `set()` of `List<T> l` that requires a known type.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Capture conversion was designed to make wildcards (in generics), `?` useful.

Suppose we have the following class:

```
public interface Test<T> {
    public void shout(T whatever);
    public T repeatPreviousShout();

}
```

and somewhere on our code we have,

```
public static void instantTest(Test<?> test) {
    System.out.println(test.repeatPreviousShout());
}
```

Because `test` is not a raw `Test` and since `repeatPreviousShout()` in "hindsight" returns a `?`, the compiler knows that there's a `T` that serves as a type parameter for `Test`.
This `T` is for some unknown `T` so the compiler erases the unknown type (for wildcard, it replaces with `Object`)., hence `repeatPreviousShout()` returns an `Object`.

But if we had,

```
public static void instantTest2(Test<?> test) {
    test.shout(test.repeatPreviousShout());
}
```

The compiler would give us an error of something like `Test<capture#xxx of ?> cannot be applied` (where `xxx` is a number, e.g. `337`).

This is because the compiler tries to do the type safety check on `shout()` but since it received a wildcard, it doesn't know what `T` represents, hence it creates a placeholder called *capture of*.

From [here (Java theory and practice: Going wild with generics, Part 1)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp04298.html), it clearly states:

> Capture conversion is what allows the
>   compiler to manufacture a placeholder
>   type name for the captured wildcard,
>   so that type inference can infer it to
>   be that type.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: One additional example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449611/can-anyone-give-me-an-example-where-the-eclipse-jdt-creates-an-ast-with-a-captur

Comment: @John, if you read the article (link provided above from IBMWorks), you'll see the example you gave comes from there.

Answer (score 5):

A parameterized type involving wildcard type arguments is really a union type. For example

```
List<? extends Number> = Union{ List<S> | S <: Number }
```

In 2 cases, instead of using `List<? extends Number>`, Java uses the captured version `List<S>`, where S is a just-created type variable with upper bound `Number`.

(1) http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html

To narrow the type of an expression. If an expression's type is `List<? extends Number>`, we know for sure that the runtime type of the object is actually a `List<S>` for some concrete type S (`S <: Number>`). So compiler uses `List<S>` instead, to perform more accurate type analysis.

Capture conversion is applied to each expression individually; this leads to some dumb results:

```
<T> void test1(List<T> a){}
<T> void test2(List<T> a, List<T> b){}

List<?> x = ...;
test1(x);    // ok
test2(x, x); // error
```

(2) http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.10.2

In subtype checking `A :< B` where `A` involves wildcard arguments. For example,

```
List<? extends Number>  :< B
<=>
Union{ List<S> | S <: Number}  :< B
<=>
List<S> :< B, for all S <: Number
```

So in effect, we are checking the captured version of type `A`