# How to create an AST with a CAPTURE binding?

Tags: java, eclipse, capture, eclipse-jdt

I am interested in using the Eclipse JDT to create a [CAPTURE](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.10) binding.

I've read several capture conversion tutorials, but when I copy-paste sample code snippets, I can never find a capture conversion binding in the Abstract Syntax Tree (using the plugin ASTView for visualizing the AST).

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Example provided by Deepak Azad @ Eclipse Forums:

```
interface Box<T> {
    public T get();
    public void put( T element);
}

class CaptureTest {
    public void rebox( Box<?> box) {
        box.get(); // return type of get() is a capture binding
    }
}
```

Comment: This example came from [Java theory and practice: Going wild with generics, Part 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20201109035143/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp04298/index.html).