# Generic: ArrayList of ? Extends ISomeInterface in Java

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, bounded-wildcard

I'm having some trouble in the following code.

```
public ArrayList<? extends IEvent> getEventsByDateRange(DateTime minStartTime,  DateTime minEndTime) 
{
    ArrayList<? extends IEvent> returnedEvents = new ArrayList<GoogleEvent>();
    returnedEvents.add(new GoogleEvent());
    return (returnedEvents);
}
```

This return the following compilation error for the "returnedEvents.add(new GoogleEvent()); line of code":

> The method add(capture#1-of ? extends IEvent) in the type
>   ArrayList is not applicable for the
>   arguments (GoogleEvent)

The declaration of the class `GoogleEvent` is as follows:

```
public class GoogleEvent implements IEvent {...}
```

I know there are some tricky parts using generics in Java, thus the wild-cards but I can't seem to figure this out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you write:

```
public List<IEvent> getEventsByDateRange(DateTime minStartTime, DateTime minEndTime)
{
    List<IEvent> returnedEvents = new ArrayList<IEvent>();
    returnedEvents.add(new GoogleEvent());
    return returnedEvents;
}
```

Comment: `ArrayList<GoogleEvent>` is not assignment compatible with `List<IEvent>`.

Comment: You cannot assign an ArrayList<GoogleEvent> to a List<IEvent>.

Comment: you cant do this .. it's not the same object type

Comment: sorry I forgot to replace the generics parameter

Comment: now you have a problem becuse you cant create an instance of IEvents it's an interface

Comment: @Mortalus: why not? You can, it a generics list, not an array. I even tried :)

Answer (score 2):

This is not allowed. `returnedEvents` contains a list of `GoogleEvent` objects and must not be allowed to accept objects that are not `GoogleEvent` objects.

Although in your example you happen to be passing a `GoogleEvent`, you are doing so by calling a version of `add` that accepts anything that implements `IEvent`. That `add` method simply isn't allowed to be called, because it could result in the list storing things other than `GoogleEvent`.

Java wildcards "edit out" methods that would break the rules in this way.

If you need to return that wildcarded list type, an `ArrayList<GoogleEvent>` satisfies it fine.

**Note** this is a complete source file that compiles without error:

```
import java.util.*;

interface IEvent { }

class GoogleEvent implements IEvent { }

public class Foo {
    public ArrayList<? extends IEvent> getEventsByDateRange()  {
        ArrayList<GoogleEvent> returnedEvents = new ArrayList<GoogleEvent>();
        returnedEvents.add(new GoogleEvent());
        return (returnedEvents);
    }
}
```

Comment: than how should i add object for the class googleEvents to the array list of objects that implements IEvents?

Comment: again at the return statment im getting Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<GoogleEvent> to ArrayList<? extends IEvent>

Comment: `List` or `ArrayList`? They are not the same.

Comment: @Mortalus - see further update, a complete source file that you can try compiling.

Comment: Thanks !!!!! work perfectly .. so now i should be able to access all the sopposobly GoogleEvents using the IEvent interface?

Comment: Yes, Java generics will allow `IEvent` methods to be called on the objects that you can retrieve from `ArrayList<? extends IEvent>`. (But as already stated, you will not be allowed to add new objects to the collection.)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `? extends IEvent` because by using only `IEvent`, Java will dynamically bind the `GoogleEvent` class. It's polymorphism.

Answer (score 2):

The solution:

```
ArrayList<IEvent> returnedEvents = new ArrayList<IEvent>();
```

The reason of your error is because the compiler is trying to do [capture conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431702/what-is-a-capture-conversion-in-java-and-can-anyone-give-me-examples/4432035#4432035).

In your case `returnedEvents` captures some *unknown* that extends `IEvent` (i.e. anything that extends/implements `IEvent`) and you're assigning it to a parameterized type `GoogleEvent`).

The compiler sees, `returnedEvents.add(? extends IEvent)` which doesn't validate with a signature of `returnedEvents.add(GoogleEvent)` as the capture placeholder is set on `returnedEvents`.

Comment: This does not compile. You cannot use a wildcard in generic instantiation.

Comment: @John B, thanks, I saw that, the page took long to update. I've updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ArrayList<IEvent> getEventsByDateRange(DateTime minStartTime,
        DateTime minEndTime)
{
    ArrayList<IEvent> returnedEvents = new ArrayList<IEvent>();
    returnedEvents.add(new GoogleEvent());
    return (returnedEvents);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot writer to a variable which is declared with `? extends ...`. Writing is only allowed when using `? super ...`.

This can be explained by the following example:

```
List<GoogleEvent> googleEvents = new ArrayList<GoogleEvent>();
ArrayList<? extends IEvent> returnedEvents = googleEvents;

// Would be OK
returnedEvents.add(new GooleEvent());

// Would be OK to the definition of returnedEvents, 
// but breaks the googleEvents.
returnedEvents.add(new OtherEvent());
```

The short solution for you is to declare returnedEvents as `List<GoogleEvent>`.

Comment: this returns Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<GoogleEvent> to ArrayList<? extends IEvent>

Comment: Use List<? extends IEvent> as result type. Which in genral is better, because you can change ArrayList to another list, e. g., LinkedList without changing the interface of the operation.

Comment: Add a cast `ArrayList<? extends IEvent> returnedEvents = (ArrayList<? extends IEvent>)googleEvents;`