# Java: How to extend a object that uses generics but limit the type

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, extends, implements

I'm sorry but i'm not sure if i used or am using the correct terminology, but basically i want to create a class called `EntityList` that extends ArrayList but i want it so that the interface I created called `EntityInterface` is basically being used for E in all instants of `EntityList` so i don't have manually declare.

code wise i want to be able to put this in

```java
 EntityList entityList = new EntityList();
```

and get the equivalent result of this

```java
 EntityList<EntityInterface> entityList = new EntityList<EntityInterface>();
```

I'm really unsure how to proceed from here. Here's was my attempt at the problem.

```java
 import java.util.ArrayList;

//right now just a class that extends ArrayList designed to hold Entities.
public class EntityList<EntityInterface> extends ArrayList<EntityInterface> {

    EntityList(){

    }
}
```

The best way i can show the problem is to show as if the arraylist is a instants variable.

```java
 import java.util.ArrayList;

//right now just a class that extends ArrayList designed to hold Entities.
public class EntityList<EntityInterface>  {

    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

    EntityList(){

    }
}
```

However this is basically what i want, again in variable form and not extends form.

```java
 import java.util.ArrayList;

//right now just a class that extends ArrayList designed to hold Entities.
public class EntityList<EntityInterface>  {

    ArrayList<EntityInterface> al = new ArrayList<EntityInterface>();

    EntityList(){

    }
}
```

I believe if i do something like this,

```java
 public class EntityList<? implements EntityInterface> extends ArrayList<?>  {
```

it should work based on this thread.
[Generic: ArrayList of ? Extends ISomeInterface in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821064/generic-arraylist-of-extends-isomeinterface-in-java)

however after trying it on eclipse with this modification of my code :

```java
public class EntityList<E implements EntityInterface> extends ArrayList<E> {
```

and 
    public class EntityList extends ArrayList {
both were throwing errors in eclipse.
I am using Java 6. I'm not sure of what sub version i'm using. I do have Java 7 if that will correct the error i'll try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`public class EntityList extends ArrayList<EntityInterface> {`

Comment: Wont that just have EntityInterface as the name if the generic type?
.
for instants how is this different from
.

     "public class EntityList extends ArrayList<e> {"

Comment: EntityList is no longer a generically typed class, so you would use it like: `EntityList list = new EntityList();`.

Comment: This looks good. Keep in mind what when you get(x) from an EntityList, you will get an EntityInterface, rather than the class of the object you actually put in.

Comment: A bit confusing. From what i could tell EntityInterface in ArrayList<EntityInterface> was being used as a name. However it works. Thank you and i will make sure add rep to your answers good sir. Glad to know i'm not the only person that has trouble sleeping.

Comment: Okay so CapnSmack has a point i didn't even think about.
I'm trying to use this as a way to sort entities in a game. can i cast the objects when i use get(x) ?