# List<List<?>> cannot be assigned to List<List<?>> when type parameter is involved

Tags: java, generics

In the following code, `get()` is called and it's result assigned to a variable whose type is `List<List<?>>`. `get()` returns a `List<List<T>>` and is called on an instance whose type parameter `T` is set to `?`, so it should fit.

```
import java.util.List;

class Test {
    void foo(NestedListProducer<?> test) {
        List<List<?>> a = test.get();
    }

    interface NestedListProducer<T> {
        List<List<T>> get();
    }
}
```

But both IntelliJ IDEA and Oracle's `javac` version 1.7.0_45 reject my code as invalid. This is the error message of 'javac':

```
java: incompatible types
  required: java.util.List<java.util.List<?>>
  found:    java.util.List<java.util.List<capture#1 of ?>>
```

Why is this code invalid, i.e. what could go wrong if it was allowed?

Comment: For example, the code could accept a `List<String>` when you receive a `List<Number>`... so yes, you should not declare your variable as `List<?>`.

Comment: @Luiggi Nowhere does my code except a `List<Number>`. `List<?>` cannot be cast to `List<Number>` so I don't see a problem.

Comment: I think the problem is that you assuming that ? == ? which is not true. Every time you put a '?' in some place in your code, it is intrinsically substituted by a fresh new unknown and unique type that is different to previous ?. you need to link those two ? so that they compiler understand that they refers to the same unknown.

Comment: @ValentinRuano Then why is this possible: `List<?> a = null; List<?> b = a;`?

Comment: Good question, you caught me there... but it does not work with List<List<?>> a = null; List<List<?>> b = a; mmmmm...

Comment: @ValentinRuano Actually, it does work with that too.

Comment: this works: `List<String> a = null; List<?> b = a;` this does not: `List<List<String>> a = null; List<List<?>> b = a;`

Comment: Two different uses of ? will not always be equivalent.  But they can be compatible (even if not equivalent) in the context of the type expressions that contains them.  I think your problem is that, in the example given, they can *never* be compatible.

Comment: Nested wildcards have a different meaning than top-level wildcards - they literally stand for "any type" as opposed to "some specific unknown type". IMHO they should've  had a different symbol, e.g. `List<List<*>>`.

Comment: Please provide *NestedListProducer* source

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`List<List<T>>` means a list that you can read `List<T>`'s from or write new `List<T>`s to, and similarly `List<List<?>>` means a list that you can read `List<?>`'s from or write new `List<T>`s to. The thing that's weird about `?` is that you can convert a list of any type `S` to a `List<?>`. For instance you can write:

```
void foo(List<String> a, List<Integer> b, List<List<?>> out) {
  List<?> unknownA = a;
  List<?> unknownB = b;
  out.add(a);
  out.add(b);
}
```

If you could convert a `List<List<T>>` into a `List<List<?>>`, you could call `foo` with a `List<List<PeanutButter>>`, and then add lists of strings and integers to it.

Generally people run into this because they're trying to express the notion that they want a collection of subcollections whose types don't matter. If that's what you want, you can change the type from `List<List<?>>` to `List<? extends List<?>>`, which expresses the notion of a list of sublists that I can read from but not write to. It is legal to convert a `List<List<T>>` to a `List<? extends List<?>>`.

Comment: This answer explains what the problem is with casting between different instances of the type `List<List<?>>` while [Rohit's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19986165/402281) explains how the type system actually prevents the code form compiling.

Answer (score 7):

The `?` is a wildcard meaning any type.  One `?` cannot be the same as another `?`, because another `?` could be any other type, and they don't match.  You must use generics to say that the types are the same:

```
// Make this generic
<A> void foo(NestedListProducer<A> test) {
    List<List<A>> a = test.get();
}
```

Comment: Why then is this possible: `void foo(List<List<?>> arg) { List<List<?>> a = arg; }`? And what would accepting the code in my question allow that could break the type system?

Comment: @Feuermurmel It is possible because there's no *capture conversion* going on in that code, as opposed to the example in your question, where the `T` is being captured.

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431702/what-is-a-capture-conversion-in-java-and-can-anyone-give-me-examples) gives a quite good explanation.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I think it's a pretty bad explanation

Comment: @Feuermurmel See [Multiple wildcards on a generic methods makes Java compiler (and me!) very confused](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546745/multiple-wildcards-on-a-generic-methods-makes-java-compiler-and-me-very-confu)

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be confused with how compiler treats a `List<?>` and a `List<List<?>>`. A `List<?>` is a *`List`* of some type that is *unknown*, whereas, `List<List<?>>` is a *`List`* of *`List`*(of different types that are *unknown*).

So for `List<?>`, the wildcard `?` represent a single unknown type, so it would be captured by the compiler to a place-holder for that single unknown type. While in `List<List<?>>`, the wildcard `?` represents different unknown types. Compiler wouldn't capture such types, as there can't be a single place-holder for different unknown types.

Now considering your original example:

```
void foo(NestedListProducer<?> test) {
    List<List<?>> a = test.get();
}
```

In this case, the compiler would capture the `?` of `NestedListProducer` to create an anonymous type parameter at compile time, and will create a helper method somewhat like:

```
<CAP#1 of ?> void foo_2(NestedListProducer<CAP#1 of ?> test) {
    List<List<?>> a = test.get();
}
```

(Note: It would not capture the `?` in `List<List<?>>`, so it will remain as it is).

Now the return type of `test.get()` in this case would be `List<List<CAP#1 of ?>>`. Which is not assignment capture convertible from `List<List<?>>`, and hence it can't be assigned to it. Thus it fails to compile.

So the workaround is to add the type parameters yourself, as already suggested:

```
<T> void foo(NestedListProducer<T> test) {
    List<List<T>> a = test.get();
}
```

---

**Query from the comments:**

Now as you asked in comments, why the following code works?

```
void foo(List<List<?>> arg) { 
    List<List<?>> a = arg; 
}
```

From above explanation, you can guess that the wildcard `?` in the `List<List<?>>` in formal parameter wouldn't be captured. Hence the assignment is really from a `List<List<?>>` to `List<List<?>>`, which is valid. There is no `CAP#1 of ?` here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this trick (wildcard capture)

```
void foo(NestedListProducer<?> test) {
    foo2(test);
}

<T> void foo2(NestedListProducer<T> test) {
    List<List<T>> a = test.get();
}
```