# Understanding captured conversion

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to undertand how captured conversion works for wildcard types. There is a section in [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10) explaining that:

> Let `G` name a generic type declaration (§8.1.2, §9.1.2) with `n` type parameters `A1,...,An` with corresponding bounds `U1,...,Un`.
>
> There exists a capture conversion from a parameterized type
>   `G<T1,...,Tn>` (§4.5) to a parameterized type `G<S1,...,Sn>`, where, for `1 ≤ i ≤ n` :
>
> - If `Ti` is a wildcard type argument (§4.5.1) of the form `?`, then `Si` is a
>     fresh type variable whose upper bound is **`Ui[A1:=S1,...,An:=Sn]`** and
>     whose lower bound is the `null` type (§4.1).
> - If `Ti` is a wildcard type argument of the form `? extends Bi`, then `Si` is
>     a fresh type variable whose upper bound is `glb(Bi,
>     Ui[A1:=S1,...,An:=Sn])` and whose lower bound is the `null` type.
>
>   `glb(V1,...,Vm)` is defined as `V1 & ... & Vm`.
>
>   It is a compile-time error if, for any two classes (not interfaces) `Vi`
>     and `Vj`, `Vi` is not a subclass of `Vj` or vice versa.
> - If `Ti` is a wildcard type argument of the form `? super Bi`, then `Si` is a
>     fresh type variable whose upper bound is **`Ui[A1:=S1,...,An:=Sn]`** and
>     whose lower bound is `Bi`.
> - Otherwise, `Si = Ti`.

The thing that is not clear to me is `Ui[A1:=S1,...,An:=Sn]`. What does it mean? I could not find a definition for that searching through the JLS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a capture conversion in Java and can anyone give me examples?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431702/what-is-a-capture-conversion-in-java-and-can-anyone-give-me-examples)

Comment: @RamanShrivastava Unfortunately, it's not. I asked about the specific part of the definition.

Comment: If you add the extra context at the start *Let G name a generic type declaration (§8.1.2, §9.1.2) with n type parameters A1,...,An with corresponding bounds **U1,...,Un**.* it becomes a little clearer what the **Ui** refers to.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon - maybe add to that with "... along with [JLS § 1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-1.html#jls-1.3) and a bit of grokking it becomes a little clearer what the `Ui` refers to"!

Comment: Although there was given a good explanation behind the notation, I believe it is still not quite clear why we need one. My understanding is that the bound is the function of type arguments. For example, in the declaration `public class Test<S extends T, T extends Number> {}`, the bound of S (`U_1`) is `Number` but once replaced by type arguments, e.g. `Test<Integer, Integer> t` the `U_1` becomes `Integer` since we can't substitute the first parameter by `Number` anymore because `S` depends on the bound of `T`. Hence, we have to look at `U_1 [A1:=S1,...,An:=Sn]` and not just simply `U_1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First:** define substitution.

`[A1:=S1,...,An:=Sn]` is a [*substitution* in JLS notation (§1.3)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-1.html#jls-1.3), defined as:

> The notation `[F1:=T1,...,Fn:=Tn]` denotes substitution of `Fi` by `Ti` for `1 ≤ i ≤ n`.

Statement: `[A1:=S1,...,An:=Sn]` is the substitution of the type *parameter* (of `G`) `Ai` by the type *variable* `Si` for `1 ≤ i ≤ n`. (also see footnote <sup>†</sup>)

**Next:** consider why we might need substitution in the first case. From [§5.1.10](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10) (highlighting added to drive home the next point):

> Let `G` name a generic type declaration ... with `n` type parameters `A1,...,An` **with corresponding bounds `U1,...,Un`**.

That is:

- the bounds `U1,...,Un` **correspond specifically to** the type parameters `A1,...,An`.
- the unstated corollary: the bounds `U1,...,Un` do not correspond to the type variables `S1,...,Sn`.

**Putting it together**: I'm now stating the obvious as I'm sure you are ahead of me, but ...

Regarding the rule for "*`Ti` is a wildcard type argument ... of the form `?`*")

> `Si` is a fresh type variable whose upper bound is `Ui [A1:=S1,...,An:=Sn]`

- `Si` is a fresh type variable
- whose upper bound is `Ui`
- *where the* (this is the implied bit)
- type parameters `A1,...,An` that `U1,...,Un` correspond specifically to
- have been substituted by the type variables `S1,...,Sn`
- making `U1,...,Un` correspond to the type variables `S1,...,Sn`

#### TL;DR

i.e. It just means that the original upper bound `Ui` is also the upper bound for `Si`

#### Footnotes

<sup>†</sup> It is helpful to recall [from the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4) that type variables and type parameters are not the same thing (hence we can start to see why we need the substitution):

> A *type variable* is an unqualified identifier used as a type in class, interface, method,
> and constructor bodies.
>
> A type variable is introduced by the declaration of a *type parameter* of a generic class, interface, method, or constructor.

Comment: BTW, couldn't you add the example of a variable that's not a fresh-type variable?

Comment: Sorry @DmitryBundin, I don't understand what you mean. The section you refer to only talks about a "fresh type variable Si"?

Comment: I meant if the restriction that Si is a __fresh__ type variable is important. I don't understand why they metntioned about that.

Comment: @DmitryBundin They just mean `Si` isn't reused from elsewhere, it's a whole new type variable declared for the capture. That's why two captures that should seemingly be the same are not - they have different captured type variables.

Comment: @AndyBrown - my thoughts on ["type parameter vs type variable"](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/java-lang-fans/5w9No6yGcRc)

Answer (score 1):

It means "substitution" of type variables with actual types. For example

```
List<T>[T:=String]    =>    List<String>

Enum<E extends Enum<E>>
    A1=E
    U1=Enum<E>

Enum<?> capture convertion to  Enum<S1>
    U1[A1:=S1]   =>   Enum<S1>
    S1's upper bound is Enum<S1>
```

The syntax is likely borrowed from [lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Substitution)