# Java generics - compile error on method parameter and method return type

Tags: java, generics

Say I've got two interfaces:

```
public interface IObjectOne<T>
{
    List<T> digest(final List<T> myList);
}

public interface IObjectTwo<T>
{
    List<T> create();
}
```

And an object which manages concrete implementations of these two interfaces, which must work over the same type.

```
public class Entity<T>
{
  private IObjectOne<T> objectOne;
  private IObjectTwo<T> objectTwo;

  ... setters

  public IObjectOne<T> getObjectOne() {
     return objectOne;
  }

  public IObjectTwo<T> getObjectTwo() {
     return objectTwo;
  }
}
```

These `Entity`s are stored in a `Map`, and I retrive one of them by a key:

```
final Entity<?> entity = entities.get(key);
```

Why cannot I do that?

```
entity.getObjectOne().digest(entity.getObjectTwo().create());
```

Comment: Answer with example very similar to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4432035/495907

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you need to do your operation in a method with a type variable:

```
<T> void doSomething(Entity<T> entity) {
  entity.getObjectOne().digest(entity.getObjectTwo().create());
}
```

You can invoke this even for an `Entity<?>`, because that wildcard has *some* type, you just don't know it.

```
final Entity<?> entity = entities.get(key);
doSomething(entity);
```

Comment: Yeah, I found I nice article by IBM (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp04298/index.html) which tells the exact same thing. I really find this to be bad coding. This means a duplicated digest() method

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
final Entity<?> entity = entities.get(key);
```

you are saying: you absolutely do not care about the exact type of an entity. Reminder: wildcard means "I don't know" about the exact type.

And *one* consequence of using the wildcard for generics, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18176765/1531124):

> If you want to enforce some relationship on the different types of method arguments, you can't do that with wildcards, you have to use type parameters.

In other words: by using the wildcard like this, the compiler is unable to correlate the generic types.

Comment: Since I do not really know what the type managed by Entity is, how can I NOT use a ? wildcard?

Comment: Wildcard means: "I don't *know*".

Comment: It doesn't mean "I don't care": it means "I don't know", and *often* you don't care. You only care if you are doing something like OP: passing the result of a producer method into a consumer method.

Comment: Reworded again.

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating the `Map<String, Entity<YOUR_TYPE>>`

You should parameterize your `Entity<>` since it is generic.

```
Map<String, Entity<YOUR_TYPE>> entities = new HashMap<>();
final Entity<YourType> entity = entities.get(key);
```