# Shouldn’t this type inference fail to compile?

Tags: java, generics, lambda, type-inference, jls

Consider the following snippet:

```java
Stream.of(stringList, Arrays.asList(1))
    .map(list -> list)
    .reduce((list1, list2) -> {list1.addAll(list2); return list1;});
```

As far as I can tell, this should not compile because the `Stream<? extends List<? extends Whatever>>` type being inferred after `map()` takes the **Capture Conversion** to a restricted type that is applicable for **only 1 execution** and when it reaches the `reduce()` function - it should change to different restricted types that are unrelated.

Calling `list1.addAll(list2)` should thus not compile.

I'm not sure how the Type Inference rules internally work for this. I would like to understand the detailed steps regarding the inference procedure for this particular case.

Note that it does not compile without the `map(list -> list)`.

---

**Edit:** based on comments of @Didier L, I would like to clarify what I mean by `applicable for only 1 execution` in the above question based on my understanding-:

- the capture conversion converts the wildcard to a **non-representable type** only for **one single expression evaluation**
- even if the variable is same - but used somewhere else in the program - the type being assumed for the next time will be different from what it was assumed before.
- if this is loop - then the capture conversion runs only for the scope of the loop - and should not escape out of the loop.
  Consider this code:

```java
List<String> stringLists = new ArrayList<>();
List<?> list = stringLists;
list.add(list.get(9)); // this will fail
```

- here `list.get(9)` will be capture converted to the type `X`
- but the `list.add(...)` may have the type `Y` - as assumed by another capture conversion of `<?>` by the compiler
- so the addition of `X` to type `Y` is not allowed because of above restriction.

Comment: For this specific case, use `Stream.concat`?

Comment: I also don't know what you'd expect here. Isn't the point that if you're looking to join the lists, you can't expect the `.map(list -> list)` to cast to a common type other that `List<?>` (or `List<? extends Serializable>`), because `List<String>` and `List<Integer>` aren't related to, say, `List<Object>`. Does it do what you expect if you use `.map(ArrayList::new)`?

Comment: The capture conversion is supposed to produce `List<X>` and `List<Y>` as the 2 distinct types - and then doing `List.addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)` should error out as X and Y are unrelated - But what I presume is that the above operation is converting both the lists to a single type List<K> and List<K> where K is the capture conversion of `? extends Serializable`.

Comment: @AndyTurner : This process seems incorrect - as ideally X  and Y are unrelated and should not be converted to the same types.

Comment: @AndyTurner : What I mean is that  `func(List<?>,List<?>)` will get capture converted to `func(List<X>, List<Y>)` and not `func(List<K>,List<K>)`

Comment: I agree that for whatever `List<? extends X>` that the compiler determines, it shouldn’t accept to call `addAll()`. I’d be curious to understand why this compiles, especially considering that compilation fails if you remove the `map(list -> list)`.

Comment: I tried to clarify the question a bit but although the general meaning seems clear, I’m not sure of exactly what you mean with “_applicable for only 1 execution […]_” and the rest of the sentence. (Maybe this question should reason about [covariance and contravariance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8481301/525036)).

Comment: Side note, I did some more tests with Eclipse (ecj), which accepts this as well. Extracting the `map()` result to a local variable will cause a compilation failure with both javac and ecj, ever when using `var` (although IntelliJ will not show an error, make sure to trigger a compilation if using it). I also noticed that the Eclipse IDE itself generates an error when hovering `list1` or `list2` (shown in the _Error Log_ view).

Comment: @DidierL : have elaborated my understanding on "only 1 execution".

Comment: @AndyTurner: have tried to edit my question - am I able to make my point this time? My question is around the detailed algorithm being followed by compiler for Type Inference in this particular case.

Comment: Yep, your point is what is described in [What is a capture conversion in Java (…)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4432035/525036). Note that in this specific case the problem would be with the lambda implementing `BinaryOperator<T>`, where `T` is used as the type of the 2 arguments of the lambda. This means those arguments have the same bounds, which is I believe the crux of the issue: the compiler infers the same capture variable when it shouldn’t. I didn’t find a way to make it print the actual types when the compilation succeeds though.

Comment: I just add a kind of revelation during the night: if you implement a `class ListBinaryOperator<T> implements BinaryOperator<List<T>>` that does the same as the lambda, that class should compile, right? And then, what should prevent using it as `reduce(new ListBinaryOperator<>())` operation? However, why does the compiler still reject it without the `map()`?